# How to receive String Array from Parse Cloud Code in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've written a Parse cloud code function which returns some data from the database. I see those in the "response" when I do a println in XCode. It looks like it's wrapped in a double optional!?
What I'm making wrong in the `if let` and in the `for` loop? How do I get (unwrap) a String Array out of it?

My code in Swift:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("TopTwo", withParameters: ["rating":5]) {
        (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(response!.count) scores.")
            println("Here are the flower names: \(response)")

            if let objects = response as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object.objectId)
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
```

What I see in the console:

```
Successfully retrieved 2 scores.
Here are the flower names: Optional((
    rose,
    "sunflower"
))
```

Maybe there is also an error in my cloude code. Here you can see what I've done:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("TopTwo", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Flowers");
    console.error("Get flowers with the rating: " + request.params.rating);
    query.equalTo("stars", request.params.rating);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            console.error("Results: " + results);

            var list = [];
            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                list[i] = results[i].get('flowerName');
            }   

            console.error("Flower name list: " + list);
            response.success(list);
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("lookup failed");
        }
    });
});
```

And here the parse logs:

```
Results: [object Object],[object Object]
Flower name list: rose,sunflower
```

(I'm using XCode 6.3.2 - Swift 1.2)
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I could solve it on my own.
The object which is returned from cloud code is already an Array. Therefore a casting into `NSArray` has to be made instead of a casting into `[PFObject]`.

Here is the working Swift code:

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("dayTopFive", withParameters: ["day":1]) {
        (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println("Successfully retrieved \(response!.count) scores.")

            // This is working: 
            let objects = response as! NSArray
            for object in objects {
                println("A top flower is: \(object)")       
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This works for me when I needed to return list of relations from user